# Website for main domain hosted on one server with sub folder hosted on another

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

I have a wordpress site hosted at hostgator that my domain is pointing to. (www.company.com)

I would like to host a second site using IIS on an Amazon server.  For example (www.company.com/clients)

Is this possible?

Comment: It's going to be way easier as a subdomain, like `clients.company.com`. Doing the folder thing is *sort of* possible, but challenging and a bit slow. It's unlikely you can do it at all on shared hosting like HostGator.

Comment: Anything is possible, but as @ceejayoz says, using a subdomain is much much easier. Otherwise you'll need a proxy / load balancer to redirect traffic.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad habit to ask "is it possible" like others commented.

If you have a full IIS server on Amazon (virtual machine), then you can install ARR on IIS to make a reverse proxy,

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

With that, you simply point the domain to this IIS machine and it can be used to distribute incoming requests to the two sites (based on incoming URLs).